# Build fails on Xcode but succeeds with run-ios

Tags: xcode, react-native

I am developing an app using react-native and I have a problem: my build is failing when trying to build using X-Code but succeeds with react-native run-ios.

The error that I am getting is this one:

```
AppDelegate.m: 'FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h' file not found
```

I am using facebook login and it works on emulator just as expected. Why am I getting different behaviors using different build methods?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. The problem was that I wasn't using the facebook's SDK "Framework Search Path" as recursive. I just changed this and now it is working. The path was

```
$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native-facebook-login/FacebookSDK
```